# Calculation {member_field} * {channel_field}

Tags: channel, entries

Is there a simple way to do this calculation on a page without using PHP on output?
I have a member_field with a value and a channel_field with a value and want to output

```
{member_field} * {channel_field} =
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way. I suggest you to install this [module](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math)

**Edit**

If incase you have values to pass with comma separated (i.e., 5,00,000.05), You need to edit `pi.math.php` file to add this code on line number 54.

```
// remove commas
$formula = str_replace("," , "" , $formula);
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this plugin can not handle values with a comma. The dec_point parameter does not react to ','. Other than that, useful answer.

Comment: Not to worry about that. Just edit the plugin `pi.math.php` and add this code on line number 54. `$formula = str_replace("," , "" , $formula);`

Comment: Have not tried that. I fear a missunderstanding. It's not the comma as a thousend separator, it's the comma as the decimal separator like in a currency like EUR 20,50. If we have EUR 20.50 the the plugin calculates. But 20,50 output is needed in Germany.

Comment: If you need to covert all `,` to use as decimal. You can change str_replace accordingly. Something like `$formula = str_replace("," , "." , $formula);`

Comment: Have inserted that line of code - one line above this: @eval("\$result = $formula;");. 2 x EUR 2,00 = EUR 400.00 is the result when Cartthrob has the decimal separator to comma. Only if it is the point then I get the result of the formula right.